# Laravel Eloquent, select only rows where the relation exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to select from a table, but I only want to select things that have an existing relationship.

For example, if I have Users and Comments, and Users haveMany Comments, I want to do something like:

```
User::hasComments()->paginate(20);
```

So, I only want to select Users that have at least 1 Comment, and paginate the result of that query. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to Laravel's Eloquent documentation for [querying relationship existence](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence), you can use the `has()` method for this:

```
User::has('comments')->paginate(20);
```

Comment: This is what I ended up using. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that `has` might use `EXISTS` correlated subquery which could be a significant performance bottleneck.

Comment: I didn't realize that, @martin. Do you know of a good alternative in that case?

Comment: I just joined the table and then `->whereNull('table.deleted_at');`

Answer (score -2):

Flip your thinking upside down and I think that you can do it.

```
$userIds = Comment::distinct()->select('user_id')->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

You may not need the `groupBy()` but that should get you started towards a way to do it.

Then you should be able to iterate through each like so:

```
foreach($userIds as $id) {
    $user = $id->user;  //$id is technically a Comment instance so you can
                        //  call the methods on that model
    echo $user->name;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Simply like this:

User::has('comments')->with('comments')->get();

Comment: You should add more explanation about your given answer.